AnyDesk Requires Manual Login to Work After Hard Shutdown on Debian
I’m facing an issue with AnyDesk on a Debian server running MATE. AnyDesk fails to work after a hard shutdown (e.g., power loss) unless I manually log in to the desktop environment (even with a monitor connected).
Details:
AnyDesk is configured to start on boot and works fine after normal reboots. However, after a hard shutdown:
The service is active (sudo systemctl status anydesk).
Connections fail until I log in locally (entering the user password) and open AnyDesk manually.
I’ve disabled “vigilant access,” so remote connections shouldn’t require manual authorization, but this seems to make no difference.
I suspect that AnyDesk or a dependency (e.g., Xorg, the graphical environment, or user session initialization) isn’t fully starting until a user logs in.
What I’ve Tried:
Enabled and verified the AnyDesk and lightdm services.
Set up a virtual display (Xvfb) to simulate a monitor.
Ensured network and DNS services are active on boot.
Goal:
Ensure AnyDesk works immediately on boot (without requiring a local login) even after a power loss.
What additional steps can I take to debug or resolve this issue? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
